# Returning parent type in C++ interfaces

Tags: c++

When using interfaces in c++; You have your abstract (parent) class. Then you have the child class which inherits from the parent class and implements the pure virtual functions.

When another class uses the (child) interface, what is the point in the abstract class at this point? If you try to use the parent type in a function, i.e returning the type Parent, you get compiler errors (presumably because the compiler doesn't know how much memory to allocate).

Can anyone tell me how to do the above?

i.e

Parent = Shape.
Child = Rectangle.
Thrid class which contains method which returns the type Shape?

Thanks in advance for any help/information.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns the type Shape". Do you mean returns a `Shape`? A `Shape*`?

Comment: Refine your Q, give examples (close to downvote).

Comment: A BoBTFish is alluding to, you cannot return a `Shape` as it is abstract and it cannot be instantiated but you can return a `Shape*` (or a `Shape` in a smart pointer).

Comment: Ah I see. I think that's what was confusing me. Thanks very much guys I think that solves my problem!

Comment: Post complete example code, this would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't think of making `Square` a child of `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big advantage is that all children share the same interface. If you have a second child inheriting from the parent (Child = Circle), then regardless of the specific subclass, both of them can use the same functions.

Imagine then that you have a vector with pointers to shapes (vector < Shape* >), then it doesn't matter which shapes you have in the vector, if your base class Shape has a virtual method Draw(), you can use that method from each element of the vector without explicit knowledge how that Draw method is implemented.

Comment: This answered my question and also tipped me off to the use of Shape* instead of Shape. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class. Period. If you have a child that you want to access through a base-class interface, then you must access the child through a pointer or reference to the base class.

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual void doit() = 0;
}

class B : public A
{
public:
  virtual void doit()
  {std::cout << "Hi.";}
}

...later, in main

A *a = new B;
a->doit(); //this calls B's implementation.
```

If you don't know why this is handy, you should research the term "polymorphism."

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returning the objects on the stack, which doesn't work because you simply cannot instantiate abstract types:

```
Parent Child::foo() {
  return Child(12);
}
```

That means, the compiler reserves (or rather, would reserve) the space for a `Parent`. And also try to copy construct `Parent`s when calling `foo`.

What you *probably* meant was this:

```
Parent* Child::foo() {
  return new Child(12); // actually you should really be using a shared pointer here, but that's a different story
}
```

This works, because the pointer to `Parent` and the pointer to `Child` have the size and alignment.

You can even directly return a `Child` because of co-variance. C++ allows you to implement `Parent* Parent::foo();` as `Child* Child::foo();` if `Child` inherits from `Parent`.